# How to open multiple files simultaneously in Python?

Tags: python-3.x, file

I have a few files (the number of which is undetermined a priori) that I'd like to read simultaneously, line by line or in chunks, do some processing and move to the next line (or chunk) in all files. I guess my requirements are more or less similar to the ones in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24108769/how-to-read-and-process-multiple-files-simultaneously-in-python). However, in my case the files can have different numbers of lines and while trying to implement something like [ExitStack](https://docs.python.org/3/library/contextlib.html#contextlib.ExitStack), noticed that all files will be closed as soon as one of them is closed (likely to be the one with the least number of lines), whereas I'd like to continue the processing of the other files (eventually assigning empty strings to the "lines" of closed files). Is this something possible to accomplish? And how?

```
#cat f1.txt
RNvn 40
AvOp 13
yEVA 94
oNGn 10
VZQU 88

#cat f2.txt
gSNn 4
zxHP 84
ebRw 70
NaxL 2
lXUb 49
PQzn 79
aIyN 88

#cat f3.txt
XXce 5
RMIq 4
FFEi 47
wuLZ 60
```

With a simple implementation of `ExitStack`, the result only includes 4 lines, because file `f3.txt` only has 4 lines:

```
flist = ['f1.txt', 'f2.txt', 'f3.txt']
with ExitStack() as stack:
    files = [stack.enter_context(open(fname)) for fname in flist]
    for lines in zip(*files):
        print(lines)

# prints
('RNvn 40\n', 'gSNn 4\n', 'XXce 5\n')
('AvOp 13\n', 'zxHP 84\n', 'RMIq 4\n')
('yEVA 94\n', 'ebRw 70\n', 'FFEi 47\n')
('oNGn 10\n', 'NaxL 2\n', 'wuLZ 60\n')
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use the best of both worlds.

The code is leaving the context `with ExitStack() as stack:` because `zip()` is exhausted on the shortest file. It has nothing to do with `ExitStack()`. Using `zip_longest()` won't exhaust until all files are finished. Then the `ExitStack()` will close the files.

```
from contextlib import ExitStack
from itertools import zip_longest

flist = ['f1.txt', 'f2.txt', 'f3.txt']
with ExitStack() as stack:
    files = [stack.enter_context(open(fname)) for fname in flist]
    for lines in zip_longest(*files):
        print(lines)
```

Comment: ohhh, the trick was actually on using `zip_longest` and it had nothing to do with `ExitStack`. Will update my answer as well.

Answer (score 0):

Answering my own question, but please feel free to add any notes/improvements/alternatives.

One way to get around this issue is to open all files, without using the `with` statement to keep reading until all files are read, and use [zip_longest](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/itertools.html#itertools.zip_longest) from `itertools` to gather all lines simultaneously. In the end close all files. Something in the lines of the code below should work:

```
from itertools import zip_longest
flist = ['f1.txt', 'f2.txt', 'f3.txt']

files = [open(i, 'rt') for i in flist]
for lines in zip_longest(*files):
    print(lines)

for f in files:
    f.close()

# this prints all lines as expected:
('RNvn 40\n', 'gSNn 4\n', 'XXce 5\n')
('AvOp 13\n', 'zxHP 84\n', 'RMIq 4\n')
('yEVA 94\n', 'ebRw 70\n', 'FFEi 47\n')
('oNGn 10\n', 'NaxL 2\n', 'wuLZ 60\n')
('VZQU 88\n', 'lXUb 49\n', None)
(None, 'PQzn 79\n', None)
(None, 'aIyN 88\n', None)
```